# Should we write "writing any stuff" or " writing any stuffs"?

Tags: grammar

What do we use with any? Stuff being a collective noun takes singular verb but again I checked the word "stuffs" is right.So those stuffs is/are?

Comment: It might be helpful if you stated exactly how you found out that "stuffs" is "right."

Comment: By googling....

Comment: _Exactly_ how? "Googling" is a very broad description. Perhaps you Googled up a site written by someone completely ignorant of the English language. We can't know unless you tell us.

Comment: Well I don't remember that now,I'm sorry. I guess I just wrote which is correct and they showed both- the 1st thing that came up in there.So " stuffs" as a noun isn't correct?

Comment: It is difficult for me to imagine how to use "stuffs" as a noun. In the absence of any exact quotation or link to the other site, I can only guess either that you were dealing with someone who does not speak ordinary American or British English, or that you misunderstood what they told you.

Answer (score 2):

**"Any stuff" is correct.** As you said, "stuff" is a collective noun, so in **nearly all** cases it should only be used in the singular form. For example,

> That *stuff* **is** expensive.
>
> This *stuff* **weighs** a lot!

We can use a collective noun in the plural when it is describing *types* of itself, but not when describing a *mass* of itself. For example:

> I bought 5 bottles of **juice** yesterday!
>
> Some of my favorite **juices** are orange, apple, and grape.
>
> Some of my favorite **kinds of juice** are orange, apple, and grape.

We are less likely to do this for "stuff", though, because if we are talking about "types of stuff", we'd probably use a more specific noun (like "substance"), instead.

More likely, whatever source stated that "stuffs" was correct was probably referring to its use as a *verb*. "To stuff" means to force something into a small area, so "She stuffs presents into our stockings every Christmas," would be correct.

Comment: As far as I remember " stuffs " was being used as a noun there. Btw thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. Thinking about it more, there are some *exceptions* where we would use "stuffs", but those are traditional, and not something we can generalize further. For example, we might talk about "foodstuffs", but that's a set term, and not something we can use for other things.

Answer (score 0):

"Stuffs" is one form of the verb "stuff", usually meaning to place an object or substance forcefully inside another object, though it does have a few other, more idiomatic meanings. "She stuffs the turkey with stuffing."

When you're using it as a noun, you just say "stuff", which refers to a general collection of objects or possessions.

Depending on the rest of the sentence, "writing any stuff" may be incorrect, regardless, and even if it's technically correct, it looks clunky; I think the more normal way of phrasing that idea might be "writing anything", though I'd probably need to see the rest of the sentence to be certain.